# Understanding !# and $@ in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scala

I've just recently started programming scala, and in the book "Programming in Scala"(www.artima.com/pins1ed) the following method of executing scala scripts in linux is presented:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
// Say hello to the first argument
println("Hello, "+ args(0) +"!")
```

Now I've been using linux for a long time, but bash scripting is not my speciality. Now I can guess how this type of scrpt works(and it works beautifully), but I was wondering what do the !# and $@ do *exactly*.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beautiful indeed. `$0` and `"$@"` are positional paramters (`$0` = command itself just like `argv[0]` in C, and `argv[1]+` for `"$@"`), whereas `#!*` tells the shell, and sometimes the kernel if it recognizes it which program to execute for the file.

The thing that happens here actually is that the shell opens the script for input reading but on the point of `exec`, it transfers the input to scala, but scala wouldn't have to read it again from the beginning since the file descriptor is still open and so scala continues reading on the next line.

Rarely do I see scripts that do that with apparent and simple presentation of how it functions.

Note that `exec` replaces the process of the shell running the script and so it's like the shell becomes scala but scala would have the environment variable and opened handlers as the same.

**UPDATE**

Looks like I was wrong. Scala itself reads the whole but skips what it could see as header lines to it. So this is the real purpose of `!#`:

*Script files may have an optional header that is ignored if present. There are two ways to format the header: either beginning with #! and ending with !#, or beginning with ::#! and ending with ::!#.*

Comment: The OP is asking about `!#`, not `#!`.

Comment: Oh, !# is a typo I believe :)

Comment: "scala wouldn't have to read it again from the beginning since the file descriptor is still open and so scala continues reading on the next line." That's not true.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes, and that's *precisely* why `!#` is needed: it separates the non-Scala header from the actual Scala code.

Comment: Ah I have to check sorry guys. I'll try to verify how this really works soon.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! Where dit you quote this from: Script files may have an optional header that is ignored if present. There are two ways to format the header: either beginning with #! and ending with !#, or beginning with ::#! and ending with ::!#

Comment: @Kapenaar It's in the Scala man page :) http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/tools/scala.html

Comment: Ok, why not simply change the shebang to `/path/to/scala` ?

Answer (score 4):

`!#` doesn't have anything to do with Bash. It's part of the Scala Language. It separates a non-Scala header from Scala Code in Script Mode.

Answer (score 2):

`"$@"` represents all the script arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about what "$@" does exactly. It passes the arguments to the script in a non-word-splitting manner. Let's see some examples:

```
$ cat echowrap
#!/bin/sh
set -x
echo $*
echo $@
echo "$@"

$ ./echowrap oneword 'two words'
+ echo oneword two words
oneword two words
+ echo oneword two words
oneword two words
+ echo oneword 'two words'
oneword two words
```

In the first example, `$*` has split the input args so that echo sees three words.The second example `$@` behaves identically. The third example `"$@"` does not undergo word-splitting, therefore echo sees the same 2 args as were originally passed.

Consider a more useful example; if you called your script as

```
$ ./scalascript 'Joe Bloggs'
```

then try changing `"$@"` into `$@` or `$*`, the shell will pass two arguments to scala, scala will see args(0) and args(1), and the output of the test program will be different.